# How to update Android app using jks file?

Tags: android, android-studio, jks

I'm in charge to do some updates for an existing Android app (already uploaded on the play store). I had just finishing coding and I want to upload the new apk to play store I looked at the gradle file and I found the KeyAlias, the store password and also the key password, I used that information with the old keystore file to generate the release apk but android studio generates password verification failed error.
What should I do?

Comment: post the error.

Comment: The error message :
Password verification errorr

Answer (score 0):

step 1) Change KeyStore password

```
  keytool -storepasswd -new newpassword -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

step 2) Change Alias key Password

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias MyKeyAlias -new newpassword -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

Note: supply old password for both keystore and alias when asked for

in changes Alias key password that ask password two time ...in first time you need to enter keystore password you changed in step 1.....in second time default password is "android"

Comment: Can't change password without using the old one

Comment: default password is "android"

Comment: i change answer...look and try again